# $E=mc^2$ tells us that everything has energy. So why can't we use anything as a battery/power source?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass-energy, antimatter, batteries

My body has mass, the floor has mass, the air has mass.

According to the formula E=MC2, we can get insane amounts of energy with very very very small mass (looking at you antimatter). However our batteries last nothing and are heavy.

Moreover, why can't we extract energy from any object with mass, like an apple or a chair? That would eventually dissipate that object from existence, but why can't we?

Answer (score 3):

We currently use this technology - of converting mass to energy - in fission reactors. For example some submarines and aircraft carriers use nuclear reactors as energy sources.([Wikipedia United States naval reactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_naval_reactors))

However we don't have the technology to convert mass of everyday objects directly into energy on a practical basis fit to replace AAA batteries.

Comment: We can but with ironically very low power levels compared to a battery http://www.citylabs.net/

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to answer this question is to flip it around.  Why would you think we can extract energy from any object with mass?

$E=mc^2$ does provide a correspondence between energy and mass, but it doesn't explain how to do it.  All it says is that if you convert energy to mass, that equation provides the exchange ratio.

For as long as we have been around, there has been energy sources that we cannot get at.  The most obvious example of this is nuclear power.  It literally was not until the 1930s that we figured out that we could harness the power of the nucleus to create usable power.  Until then, we were *surrounded* by nuclei, but had no way to harness them.  In fact, even after we figured out that nuclei could release energy, it still took a solid 10 years before anyone actually demonstrated a contraption that could do it!

For the majority of human history, we have been surrounded by energy that we cannot harness in a usable form.  I do not expect that to change in the future.

It is entirely possible that we have a technology coming down the pipe that is going to permit the sudden conversion of rest mass into energy.  However, we simply haven't found it yet.  Until then, Einstein's equations serve as a demonstration of what the exchange rate can be.